# Angular.js dynamic template with different url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a page with a static header and footer layout, but using ng-view or ng-include to change my container template based on the URL.  I've tried two methods:

Using $routeProvider:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl',
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/contact-us', {
        template: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl',
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

or a controller function to return a template URL:

```
app.controller('locationCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.templateUrl = function() {
        return "/views/home.html";

    }
});
```

However, with either one I get am unable to get a contact-us error message.

Comment: so I have a www.domain.com and this will loads my home.html. and www.domain.com/contact-us will loads my contact.html

Comment: What happens when user browses w/ JavaScript turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'Ctrl',
});
$routeProvider.when('/contact-us', {
    template: 'views/contact.html',
    controller: 'Ctrl', // Controller should be different
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
}]);
```

Replace To :

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) 
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html', //template should be templateUrl
    controller: 'Ctrl',
});
$routeProvider.when('/contact-us', {
    templateUrl: 'views/contact.html', //template should be templateUrl
    controller: 'Ctrl',
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
}]);
```

Your 1st method will work.

Comment: Thanks It works on home.html but when in contact-us, seems it keep reloading the page.

Comment: I'd recommend not recycling controllers for fundamentally separate routes. You wouldn't do this with MVC so it's not advisable with Angular despite being possible.

Comment: yeah I did, but it just keep reloading. Sorry I have no idea why its happening.

Comment: $routeProvider.when('/contact-us', {
      templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
     }); 
Here include Controller

http://jsfiddle.net/NYgUT/3/

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but still the index page keep rendering ( reloading? )

Comment: I found that its the Ctrl controller is causing it, but no clue why

Comment: ok i am an idiot, i open up two contact.html and modify the wrong one. now its fixed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

routerProvider runs before all of controllers. So you can't simply change templateUrls dynamically. But you can use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) conditionally:

```
<div ng-controller="SubPageCtrl>
    <ng-include src="templateUrl"></ng-include>
</div>
<script>
function SubPageCtrl($scope) {
    if ( something ) {
         $scope.templateUrl = '/some.html';
    } else {
         $scope.templateUrl = '/other.html';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your routes from more specific urls to more general urls. Because routes match with urls that start with your definition.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/contact-us', {
        template: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl',
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl',
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```